# Creating a custom collection of custom classes in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, collections, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

In the iOS app I'm building, I am currently managing a list of objects (Tasks) by using an NSMutableArray containing a number of NSMutableDictionary objects for each individual task.

I would now like to encapsulate the logic I'm writing for managing these tasks in a custom class or classes.

Here are a few options I'm considering:

1. Create a single new class called TaskManager which uses the above classes internally and exposes the necessary methods for adding, removing, updating, reordering, etc.
2. Create two classes -- Task and TaskList -- which inherit from NSMutableDictionary and NSMutableArray respectively
3. Create two classes -- Task and TaskList -- which inherit from NSObject but which use the other classes internally to store the data

I've done some C# development before but I'd be keen to get some advice for which approach would be best in Objective C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest option 4:

- A class TaskList that uses an NSMutableArray internally
- A class Task that uses properties, but no NSMutableDictionary

Or is there a reason you'd want to use a dictionary? If you use a regular class, you'll get type safety (and also better performance).

Comment: Thank you. That makes complete sense. I think I was thinking about using the standard classes because they can be saved easily to a plist. But I will look at different solutions for that.

Answer (score 0):

If I would at you place I will be creating one Custom Class which encapsulate classes like below.

**TaskManager.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface TaskManager : NSObject

@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *taskList;

-(void)addTaskList:(NSMutableDictionary *)object;

@end


@interface Task : NSObject

@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableDictionary *taskDetails;

-(void)setTaskDetailsWithKey:(NSString*)key withValue:(NSString*)value;

@end
```

**TaskManager.m**

```
#import "TaskManager.h"

@implementation TaskManager
@synthesize taskList;

-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        if(!taskList)
            taskList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)addTaskList:(NSMutableDictionary *)object
{
    [taskList addObject:object];
}

@end

@implementation Task

@synthesize taskDetails;

-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        if(!taskDetails)
            taskDetails = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}


-(void)setTaskDetailsWithKey:(NSString*)key withValue:(NSString*)value
{
    [taskDetails setObject:value forKey:key];
}

@end
```